# Entity Framework/Database modeling a chores list

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, database-design

I'm developing an Asp.net mvc application with entity framework so that I can more easily create dish lists and chore lists for me and my roommates from month to month. I'm trying to model our chore list but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to model it clear and effective way that will make development smooth.

Here is a sample screen shot of the chores list
[image]

Chores are done on Mondays and Thursdays. Each chore has a person assigned to it and each chore has anywhere from 4 to 6 different tasks that must be complete.

I'm hoping to make an app that can generate this kind of chart. It doesn't need to hold information about whether a specific box is checked or not, it will be printed off.

But the way the system works is this. It allows the user to create a list of jobs and tasks such as kitchen, living room, and bathroom. And then the user can generate a monthly chore list where the chores are brought up and the person can be selected for each chore. Once this is complete and the user clicks a generate button, the list for the month is generated.

However, I want the system to be able to retain what house jobs were on which month and which users were on which job. I want the system to able to bring back this information even if the current jobs are edited and changed. This is where I'm confused. How would I be able to do this??? Should I make some sort of historical table that copies all of the rows from a chorestable when a chore list is generated? Any input or ideas where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you just need a user table, chore table and userchore table that links the 2 and has a month field.. or .. user.. area.. chore.. userarea.... chores assigned to area.. area assigned to user..

Answer (score 0):

Create next tables:

1. Chores     (Id, Date, RoommateId(link to Roommates), ChoreName, ChoreDescription, RoomId, WorkDate, ...)
2. ChoreTypes (Id, Name, Description)
3. Rooms      (Id, Name, Descirption)
4. Roommates  (Id, FirstName, LastName, ....)

If you will keep text from ChoreTypes dictionary in Chores table, then it will not change if you update ChoreTypes.